# Symfony 3 Translate error validators range

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony, translate

I want to translate the following error message of Range : 
**This value should be Jan 1, 1990, 12:00 AM or more.**

I'm using the function of Symfony that works for my other errors except this one :

`$this->get('translator')->trans($err, [], 'validators')`

Should i use something else to translate this error ?

Comment: what is the value of $err? and what contain the validators files?

Comment: Do you use `@Assert\Range` or something similar? If so, you can simply translate the message by entering the id in `message="my_range_message"`, where `my_range_message` is found in your `validators.en.yml`, `validators.fr.yml` and so on. Translations of validation messages should be done in the model (entity) rathen than in the controller, unless you have some specific requirements.

Comment: @Matteo : I've this on the $err :  This value should be Jan 1, 1990, 12:00 AM or more.

Comment: @cezar Yes that's right i use this Range, but yes i found the id of the translation but i don't know how to call the right one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correct understand, you can proceed how cezar suggest, as example, you can use the annotation:

<kbd>MyEntity.php</kbd>

```
/**
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = "now",
 *      max = "+5 hours",
 *      minMessage = "myMinMessage"
 * )
 */
private $myDate;
```

And add the translation in your files, as example:

<kbd>validators.en.yml</kbd>

```
myMinMessage: bla bla value should be {{ limit }} or more. You entered {{ value }}
```

hope this help